# For 2nd application should I produce my transcript

Tags: phd

After doing my BE in production engineering I got admission in a university inUSA for PhD on industrial engineering but  got 2.90 gpa in first semester as I don't have the background. In future if I apply again for PhD should I produce my transcript?

Answer (score 4):

At least for US universities, it's usual for applications to require official transcripts from all colleges and universities you have attended.  In that case, yes, you do have to send them a transcript from your previous PhD program.  (Actually, it's usually required that you get the university to send it directly.)